# Unique values in kendoAutoComplete

Tags: kendo-grid, kendo-autocomplete

```
$('#Name).kendoAutoComplete({
    dataTextField: "customerName",
    filter: "startswith",
    dataSource: orderModelDS.ordersSource
    });
```

This is the code where I am using autocomplete as a custom filter on a kendoGrid. In the dataSource there is data with same customerName. So the autocomplete is also showing duplicate values.

If there is multiple data with same customerName, autocomplete list should show the customerName only once because the rest are duplicates. But it is not happening autocomplete list is showing the same name multiple times.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Is there any one to help me I really need this feature.

Comment: Filtering for distinct values is not yet supported in kendo. You would have to filter it on the server side. See http://www.telerik.com/forums/how-to-show-unique-values-and-auto-complete-in-drop-down#SsfM4FrkmEuoqMJsr84YQQ

Comment: Thanks for the advice I will try to add a server side filtering and see.